# Spring 3.x Validation, @Valid and 2 Duck methods

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am having a problem figuring out the @Valid tag and proper usage - would greatly appreciate any help!

Say I have a REST controller that does simple CRUD operations on a Duck (I need to use something to illustrate!).  Let's look at creating and updating ducks.   In both cases, I need to pass in the entire Duck, first to create it, second because it is possible to modify any of  it's data items.  So these methods would look something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ducks", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Duck> createDuck(@Valid @RequestBody Duck duck) {  ... }
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ducks/{duckId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Duck> updateDuck(@Valid @RequestBody Duck duck) { ... }
```

I have inserted the "@Valid" on each parameter because I want to validate each of the calls.   The @Valid tag seems appealing here as I can validate the entire object upon receipt as opposed to using disparate JSR 303 annotations further down the food chain.   Since (maybe) I have other methods in this controller that don't take a Duck, I enable the @Valid with:

```
@InitBinder("duck")
protected void initBinder(DataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new MyDuckValidator());
}
```

where MyDuckValidator implements the org.springframework.validation.Validator interface.

The problem is that I want the Id (primary key) passed in on the "updated Duck" to be validated to be non-Null.  But when I create a Duck, it is perfectly valid for that Id to be null.  This seems like "Validation 101", but I can't seem to figure it out from any of the examples or documentation.   Does anyone know of a simple solution?  I don't mind have two validators and wiring those in.  However, I do not want to corrupt the API just to work around Validation....